# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error:

Tags: java, hibernate

I have written the following code but its showing a compile time error that -

> Transaction could not be resolved to a type

Even though I have imported `org.hibernate.Transaction`.

Could you please help. Following is my code:

```
package mypackage;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Mainclass {
public static void main(String[] args) {  

    //creating configuration object  
    Configuration cfg=new Configuration();  
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");//populates the data of the configuration file  

    //creating seession factory object  
    SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();  

    //creating session object  
    Session session=factory.openSession();  

    //creating transaction object  
    Transaction t= (Transaction)session.beginTransaction();  

    Employee e1=new Employee();  
    e1.setId(115);  
    e1.setFirstName("sonoo");  
    e1.setLastName("jaiswal");  

    session.persist(e1);//persisting the object  

    try {
        t.commit();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    session.close();  

    System.out.println("successfully saved");  
   }
}
```

Comment: is Hibernate correctly included in your classPath ?

Comment: yes I have included all the jars , how do I show you here what all jars I have include ..I am new here so kindly help.

Comment: Get a screenshot of build path (if using eclipse) or console and paste into the question

Comment: Is this the only error you are getting? Or are you getting other errors? Do you get any error in your `import` lines?

Comment: Have Jta in your classpath ?

Comment: I am getting this error in the line Transaction t= (Transaction)session.beginTransaction();

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code as written.  It *should* compile.  There is a type called `org.hibernate.Transaction` - it is an interface.

So why might this not compile?

- Maybe the above one isn't the version of the source code that you are compiling.
- Maybe the compiler's build classpath is incorrect.
- Maybe you are somehow mixing up the versions of the hibernate JAR files, and / or you are missing the JAR that contains >>that<< class.